# Reasoning behind custom class Exception

Tags: python, exceptions

I am learning Python and when I learned that we can build Custom classes for exception, I got into a confusion of Why ?

for example1 :

```
class MyException(Exception):
      def __init__(self, error):
           self.error = error
      def __str__(self):
          # DO THE WORK TO BE DONE FOR THE EXCEPTION
          print  "Here is my custom made exception" + self.error
```

example 2 :

```
try:
  # SOMETHING
except Exception:
  # DO THE WORK TO BE DONE FOR THE EXCEPTION
  raise Exception("Here is my custom made exception - Whats the reason ?")
```

If example 2 does the same work as example1, Why do we need custom exception. Is there a scenario why I needed a custom exception when I could just do everything I needed inside except block.

Comment: Example 1 and 2 does completely different things. Example one defines an exception class, while example 2 is some code which catches a exception and throws another exception. You should probably clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you *throw* Exceptions?

Because something's happened that you can't deal with and you need to tell whoever called you that it did, in a well-defined, structured manner.

Why do you *catch* Exceptions?

Because you can can do something *useful* with/ about them.

How can you tell that you can handle a particular Exception?

You know what *Type* it will be so that you can filter that from all the other Exceptions that might come your way.

You absolutely never, *ever* try to recognise an Exception based on its *Message*.  If somebody [else] changes the wording in the original Message (like translating it into another language), your application will crash and burn because your "catch" won't recognise it any more.  Also, you have to catch the Exception before you can test its Message property and that makes a complete *mess* of how Structured Exception Handling is supposed to work.

How do you go about "fixing" [the cause of] the Exception?

You make use of the *additional properties* included in the custom Exception.

If you don't *need* any additional properties to fix the cause, then you'll still need a custom exception class (so that you can filter it).  Only if all you're going to do is log the exception and let the program die can you get away without having a custom Exception class.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest reason for implementing your own exception is that you can filter on it. If you have an `except` block which names your exception, then it won't catch anything except your custom exception (and anything subclassed from that).

Comment: I am sorry but I am still not clear on it, can you please explain with an example ?

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions can do more than just store string messages for log output.

You might be programming a system for patient records, and need to enforce security access level rules. For example, that might lead you to have `SecurityViolationException`, which stores related information about the incident: `denied_resource`, `infringing_employee`, `time`, etc. So when you throw a `SecurityViolationException`, you'll fill it with contextual information about the incident, that can be used up the chain to respond to the incident more accurately.